# Azure Speech-to-Text web socket in Flutter

Tags: flutter, azure, websocket, speech-to-text

I am building a Flutter application and I want to integrate continuous Speech-to-Text recognition. For continuous recognition to work, I need to connect with Azure Speech-to-Text via web socket. I found a documentation for REST and for the SDKs (there is no SDK for Flutter). But not for web socket. How can I connect to Azure STT with a web socket?

I tried to open a web socket connection with this URL:
`wss://<endpoint_url>/speech/recognition/continuous?language=<language_code>&format=<audio_format>&subscription-key=<subscription_key>`

Comment: Hello were you able to find anything regarding this ?

Comment: No, i just implemented and deployed it in web and then used a webview in my flutter app.